# How to carry over header info to errorChannel?

Tags: spring-integration

In my application, my gateway is receiving request identifier in header, whenever error happens, error channel receives the exception. But it seems like, errorChannel don't take the headers from gateway.

Is it possible to carry over the header information to error channel as well?

Sample example:
sysout in sampleErrorChannel does not has the header which i have passed.

https://github.com/manojp1988/spring-integration/blob/master/javadsl/src/main/java/ErrorChannel/ErrorChannelExample.java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message on the error channel is an `ErrorMessage`, it has a payload of `MessagingException` which has two properties, the `cause` (exception) and `failedMessage`.

You can access the failed message headers that way.

e.g. `payload.failedMessage.headers['foo']` when using SpEL.

If using a POJO service activator on the error flow, you can use

```
public void failure(MessagingException failure) {
    MyHeader mh = failure.getFailedMessage().getHeader("mh");
}
```

Comment: I am trying to put headers into my new message, but my thread keep on waiting. How to enrich my response with headers from failedMessage?
headers = payload.getFailedMessage().getHeaders();
Message m = new GenericMessage(response, headers);

Comment: Don't do that; you need to keep the proper replyChannel header from the error flow - the old replyChannel is spent and nobody is listening to it. Try `MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(errorMessage.getHeaders()).copyHeadersIfAbsent(failedMessage.getH‌​eaders()).build();`. This should keep the proper replyChannel in place. Or, build it from the failed message and copy back the replyChannel header from the ErrorMessage.