# Unable to set Reply Channel to Message Header in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

There is definitely something I must be missing so seeking help here.

I am building a simple REST application using Spring Integration with the following HTTP inbound gateway:

```
<!-- Gateway -->
    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="fruitQuotePOSTGateway"
                              request-channel="fruitQuotePOSTRequests"
                              supported-methods="POST"
                              path="/api/v1/fruit-quote"
                              request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                              reply-timeout="10000"
                              reply-channel="fruitQuotePOSTResponses"
                              error-channel="applicationErrors">
        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/xml" produces="application/xml"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

Once a  XML enters this gateway, it undergoes the following simple steps:

- Transformation to generate the JAXB object corresponding to the incoming request
- Message header enrichment that reads a "uuid" from the JAXB Object and sets it to the header of the SI (Spring Integration) message
- Transformation to generate a  XML response to the calling client.

To start with, here is the XML configuration of the entire application (omitted the HTTP namespaces, for brevity):

```
<!-- Gateway -->
    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="fruitQuotePOSTGateway"
                              request-channel="fruitQuotePOSTRequests"
                              supported-methods="POST"
                              path="/api/v1/fruit-quote"
                              request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                              reply-timeout="10000"
                              reply-channel="fruitQuotePOSTResponses"
                              error-channel="applicationErrors">
        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/xml" produces="application/xml"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <!--
    - Generate fruit quote request JAXB from the incoming request
    - Create a header "requestUUID" by reading it from fruit quote request JAXB
    - Generate fruit quote acknowledgement response for the calling client
    -->

    <int:transformer input-channel="fruitQuotePOSTRequests"
               ref="fruitQuoteTransformation"
               method="generateFruitQuoteRequestJAXB"/>

    <int:header-enricher input-channel="requestUUIDEnrichment" output-channel="orderIDGeneration">
        <int:header name="requestUUID" expression="payload.getFruitQuoteRequestJAXB().getFRUITQUOTEREQUESTDATA().getUuid()"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:transformer input-channel="fruitQuoteAcknowledgementGeneration"
                     ref="fruitQuoteTransformation"
                     method="generateFruitQuoteAcknowledgement"
                     output-channel="fruitQuotePOSTResponses"/>

    <!-- Error handling -->
    <int:transformer input-channel="applicationErrors"
                     ref="fruitQuoteTransformation"
                     method="generateFruitQuoteAcknowledgementWithError"
                     output-channel="fruitQuotePOSTResponses"/>

    <!-- Channels -->
    <int:channel id="fruitQuotePOSTRequests"/>
    <int:channel id="requestUUIDEnrichment"/>
    <int:channel id="fruitQuotePOSTResponses"/>
    <int:channel id="fruitQuoteAcknowledgementGeneration"/>
    <int:channel id="applicationErrors"/>
```

The payload flowing from one step to another in the application is a custom Builder Object as follows (omitted the package name):

```
import static java.util.Objects.nonNull;

public class FruiteQuoteComposite {
    private final FRUITQUOTEREQUEST fruitQuoteRequestJAXB;
    private final FruitQuoteApplicationException fruitQuoteApplicationException;
    private final Integer orderID;
    private final ErrorInformation errorInformation;

    private FruiteQuoteComposite(FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder fruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder) {
        this.fruitQuoteRequestJAXB = fruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder.fruitQuoteRequestJAXB;
        this.fruitQuoteApplicationException = fruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder.fruitQuoteApplicationException;
        this.orderID = fruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder.orderID;
        this.errorInformation = fruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder.errorInformation;
    }

    public FruitQuoteApplicationException getFruitQuoteApplicationException() {
        return fruitQuoteApplicationException;
    }

    public FRUITQUOTEREQUEST getFruitQuoteRequestJAXB() {
        return fruitQuoteRequestJAXB;
    }

    public Integer getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public ErrorInformation getErrorInformation() {
        return errorInformation;
    }

    public static class FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder {
        private FRUITQUOTEREQUEST fruitQuoteRequestJAXB;
        private FruitQuoteApplicationException fruitQuoteApplicationException;
        private Integer orderID;
        private ErrorInformation errorInformation;

        public FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder() {
        }

        public FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder setFruitQuoteRequestJAXB(FRUITQUOTEREQUEST fruitQuoteRequestJAXB) {
            if (nonNull(fruitQuoteRequestJAXB)) {
                this.fruitQuoteRequestJAXB = fruitQuoteRequestJAXB;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder setFruitQuoteApplicationException(FruitQuoteApplicationException fruitQuoteApplicationException) {
            if (nonNull(fruitQuoteApplicationException)) {
                this.fruitQuoteApplicationException = fruitQuoteApplicationException;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder setOrderID(Integer orderID) {
            if(nonNull(orderID)) {
                this.orderID = orderID;
            }

            return this;
        }

        public FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder setErrorInformation(ErrorInformation errorInformation) {
            if (nonNull( errorInformation )) {
                this.errorInformation = errorInformation;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public FruiteQuoteComposite build() {
            return new FruiteQuoteComposite(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I didn't use "output-channel" on the transformers is because I wanted to explicitly choose the replyChannel/outgoing route inside the java logic running the transformation.

For instance, inside the **FruitQuoteTransformation.generateFruitQuoteRequestJAXB** method, I set one route for success and another route for exceptions/errors as follows:

```
public Message<FruiteQuoteComposite> generateFruitQuoteRequestJAXB(Message<String> fruitQuoteRequestMessage) {
        String fruitQuoteRequest = fruitQuoteRequestMessage.getPayload();
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
        FRUITQUOTEREQUEST fruitQuoteRequestJAXB;

        try {
            unmarshaller = requireNonNull(fruitQuoteRequestJaxbContext).createUnmarshaller();
            fruitQuoteRequestJAXB = (FRUITQUOTEREQUEST) requireNonNull(unmarshaller)
                    .unmarshal(new StringReader(fruitQuoteRequest));
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
            logger.error("JAXB Unmarshalling exception occurred with error code :: " + ERR_FRUIT_QUOTE_REQUEST_JAXB_TRANSFORMATION, jaxbException);
            FruitQuoteApplicationException fruitQuoteApplicationException = generateFruitQuoteApplicationException(ERR_FRUIT_QUOTE_REQUEST_JAXB_TRANSFORMATION, MESSAGE_FRUIT_QUOTE_INTERNAL_SYSTEM_ERROR);

            FruiteQuoteComposite outboundFruitQuoteComposite = new FruiteQuoteComposite.FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder()
                    .setFruitQuoteApplicationException(fruitQuoteApplicationException)
                    .build();

            return withPayload(requireNonNull(outboundFruitQuoteComposite))
                    .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, "applicationErrors")
                    .build();
        }

        FruiteQuoteComposite outboundFruitQuoteComposite = new FruiteQuoteComposite.FruiteQuoteCompositeBuilder()
                .setFruitQuoteRequestJAXB(fruitQuoteRequestJAXB)
                .build();

        return withPayload(requireNonNull(outboundFruitQuoteComposite))
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, "requestUUIDEnrichment")
                .build();
    }
```

- **My 1st question** 
  For some reason, the **.setHeader** invocation isn't working as expected and the message isn't going to the next channel. Is there something I am missing? The result is the same even when I use **.setReplyChannelName**.
- **My 2nd question** 
  In case there is a solution to question 1), keeping the overall SI configuration as XML-based, is there an alternate approach to setting customized reply channels? The only option that came to my mind were using a router after every single transformer but this seemed too verbose.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never mess with the framework's `replyChannel` header; it is not intended for routing purposes.

The `replyChannel` is an internal channel, unique to each message used to correlate a reply to a request. You generally don't need an explicit `reply-channel` on the inbound gateway; if you do, it is simply bridged at runtime to the message's replyChannel header.

Error conditions should be handled on the gateway's `error-channel` instead by throwing an exception. Different errors can be signaled by different exception types.

Comment: Oh ok - this is an important learning for me! Using your idea of using the nearest gateway's error-channel as the safety net for all exceptions, in order to achieve this, is it OK to  simply throw application-level exceptions (from whichever transformer/service-activator method applicable) and expect them to land in the gateway's error-channel as  Message<MessagingException>s with the MessagingException payload storing the underlying application-specific exception as the "cause"?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Indeed your exception is going to be there as a cause

Comment: Thanks Artem! I will implement this and post back.

Comment: @ArtemBilan This works! Have another question now: When the gateway's error-channel comes into play, doesn't the Message<MessagingException> retain the headers from the previous message? Specifically, in a flow like "splitter->gateway->http-outbound-gateway->aggregator", I am putting a generated uuid in the message headers of the splitter's output so I can re-use them as correlation strategy in the aggregator. My idea is to aggregate both success messages as well as failed ones (coming via the error-channel). In this case, I was hoping to retrieve the "uuid" from the failed messages also.

Comment: The flow in my comment above is based on the lines of the <int:chain> mentioned by @ArtemBilan in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227506/spring-integration-how-to-use-an-error-gateway-with-splitter-aggregator-when

I would like to aggregate messages coming from both the "processError" path as well as the success path, hopefully using custom-set UUIDs that are set to all the messages leaving the splitter.

Comment: I got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778650/how-to-carry-over-header-info-to-errorchannel

Given "Message<MessagingException> messagingExceptionMessage", messagingExceptionMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders() produced all the headers of the failed message!

Comment: That's great that you search and read (& post back here) faster that I would prepare an answer for you ;-)

Comment:  Sure thing! Thanks again Artem & Gary.